# CSS3 :hover effect for child element - Firefox and Explorer doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="home-product-display-box">
  <div>Lots of other stuff</div>
  <div class="fb-home-holder">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="www.myurl.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" ></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home-product-display-box .fb-home-holder {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
    display:none;
}

.home-product-display-box:hover .fb-home-holder {
     display:block !important;
}
```

This works as intended for Webkit (Chrome and Safari), but does not work for Firefox and Internet Explorer. I intend to hide the Facebook div and show it on hover over the parent element, but it doesn't show. Why does this not work properly for these two browsers?

Comment: How can you hover a div that has no rendered content?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to show the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:none` doesn't receive mouse hover, but you can use `opacity:0`:

```
 .home-product-display-box .fb-home-holder {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px; 

    /*CHANGE OPACITY*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0); /*ie*/
    -moz-opacity: 0;         /* Mozilla extension */
    -khtml-opacity:0;        /* Konqueror extension (Safari 1.1)*/
    opacity: 0;              /* the correct CSS3 syntax */
}

.home-product-display-box:hover .fb-home-holder {
    /*CHANGE OPACITY*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100); /*ie*/
    -moz-opacity: 1;         /* Mozilla extension */
    -khtml-opacity:1;        /* Konqueror extension (Safari 1.1)*/
    opacity: 1;              /* the correct CSS3 syntax */
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/epozag/6/edit

Comment: Great, using opacity instead worked! By the way, what do you mean by display:none doesn't receive mouse hover? And why does only Webkit allow to change the display property??

Comment: Using `display:none` means the DIV that you want to receive the hover event has no literal browser real estate for the mouse to interact with. `visibility:hidden` avoids this issue by keeping the real estate for the DIV in question, but only hiding the actual contents, not the contents AND dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have given it is impossible that it works.

When you set the content of you `.home-product-display-box` to `display: none;` and have not set a width and height for it, the div adjust it's sizes to the sizes of the content. In your case 0px width and 0px height.

So there is nothing to hover.

Comment: You are mistaken.  `.home-product-display-box` is **not** set to `display: none`.  Look at the target again: `.home-product-display-box .fb-home-holder`.

Comment: No, I'm not mistaken. If you read my answer carefully then you see that I have written the content of `.home-product-display-box` is set to `display: none;`. And the content is `.fb-home-holder`

Comment: The OP is targeting `.fb-home-holder` with `display:none`.  And therefore `.home-product-display-box` does **not** have `0px` width & height as you've stated.  See OP's code again:  `<div>Lots of other stuff</div>` is also inside the `.home-product-display-box` container.

Comment: Very funny, that div was edited in the question later (after my answer)